# How do I make an item rare?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need help, I am so excited that this map is getting good, I have been asking a whole lot of questions with command blocks, but this time I need a script. What do I need to change here to make an item rare?

```
"rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:map",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "exploration_map",
              "destination": "buriedtreasure"
```

or

```
"rolls": 3,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "item",
          "name": "minecraft:compass",
          "weight": 1
        },
```

Comment: That command seems incomplete

Comment: oh ok i will edit it